# What is the protocol for commands sent via xbee.send()?

Tags: python, xbee, zigbee, mesh-network

I would like to use `Digi XStick2 ZB` (connected via USB and visible as serial interface on `/dev/ttyUSB0`) as a ZigBee controller for a bunch of ZigBee sensors and actuators (temperature and humidity, contact sensor, water leakage, power plug,...). In other words, I am looking for the way to configure mesh network and to communicate with sensors/actuators.

I found [python xbee](https://python-xbee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and wrote a simple python script to communicate with the USB stick:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
from xbee import ZigBee

def print_data(data):
    print "Data received:", data

serial_port=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
zbee = ZigBee(serial_port, callback=print_data)

print "Sending some command"
zbee.send("at", frame='A', command='MY', parameter=None)
print "Waiting..."
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

zbee.halt()
serial_port.close()
```

It works, and I get some response to my command:

```
$ ./test.py 
Sending some command
Waiting...
Data received: {'status': '\x00', 'frame_id': '\x01', 'parameter': '\x00\x00', 'command': 'MY', 'id': 'at_response'}
```

But I can't find anything about the protocol used (namely, content of the messages I can send) - is there some command reference or protocol definition I can use?

Alternatively, is there an easier way (higher level library?) to control sensors via USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I found the answer shortly after asking... I looks like XBee ZB supports two modes:

- AT mode: https://eewiki.net/display/Wireless/XBee+AT+Mode+-+Transmit+and+Command+Mode+Example
- API mode: https://eewiki.net/display/Wireless/XBee+API+Mode+-+Read+Remote+ADC+Example

To quote:

> This example demonstrates XBee operation in AT mode.  AT mode is
>   synonymous with "Transparent" mode.  In AT mode, any data sent to the
>   XBee module is immediately sent to the remote module identified by the
>   Destination Address in memory.  When the module is in AT mode, it can
>   be configured by the user or a host microcontroller by first placing
>   the module in Command mode and then sending predefined AT commands
>   through the UART port.  This mode is useful when you don't need to
>   change destination addresses very often, or you have a very simple
>   network, or simple point to point communication.  For larger networks
>   that involve nodes talking to multiple targets, API mode is more
>   useful.  In API mode, rather than sending AT commands serially, data
>   packets are assembled that include the Destination Address.  API mode
>   allows you to change destination address much more quickly because
>   Command Mode doesn't need to be entered.  API mode is also useful if
>   the user needs to change the configuration of a remote module.  This
>   project focuses on AT mode operation.

Articles contain the link to documentation for both modes: https://eewiki.net/download/attachments/24313921/XBee_ZB_User_Guide.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1380318639117&api=v2

---

A short working example is now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
from xbee import ZigBee

def print_data(data):
    print "Data received:", data

serial_port=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
xbee = ZigBee(serial_port, callback=print_data)

xbee.send("at", frame='A', command='SH', parameter=None)
xbee.send("at", frame='A', command='SL', parameter=None)
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

xbee.halt()
serial_port.close()
```

Output:

```
Data received: {'status': '\x00', 'frame_id': '\x01', 'parameter': '\x00\x01\x02\x03', 'command': 'SH', 'id': 'at_response'}
Data received: {'status': '\x00', 'frame_id': '\x01', 'parameter': '\x04\x05\x07\x07', 'command': 'SL', 'id': 'at_response'}
```

This retrieves serial number of the controller (`01020304050607` in this case).

Hope it helps someone.